# SQL Data modeling -Querying Records that have tags across multiple categories

Tags: sql, odata, hana, datamodel, columnstore

I have a table that stores different software services a company offers. The services are tagged by the Industry it serves, the LoB it belongs to, and the technology involved in the service. The service can have multiple tags on each of Industry,LOB, and Technology.

For eg: Following could be the master data:

[image]

And a transaction data could look like this :

[image]

I need to create a view that can be used to query data by Industry/LoB and Technology tags. For time being I've Left outer joined all tagtoService relation tables(service-technology, service-LoB, Service-Industry tables) to the services transaction table. but this goes for a huge number of records as it is possible to typically have one service tagged to up to 10-15 industries and technologies.

Just wanted to know what is the optimal way to model this data so that I have provision to query for service by all of the three tags right from within one view.

I am not a Data modeling expert and this is more of my first venture into the data modeling side- so please pardon the 'noob'ness of my question :). I use SAP HANA as the database and expose data via an OData service for which I want to use this view as a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking modeling the data: Normally in your transaction table, you keep the foreign keys, not the text columns that can be obtained via foreign keys from the master tables. I bet that's what you meant as well but the example shows text values in the transaction tables.

Other than that, I think what you have is sound and reasonable. These "tag" tables represent different level of granularity for the "services" table and it can be counterproductive if you combine them in a single table (examples: single column with comma separated tags, XML / JSON columns, multiple columns [LOBTag1, LOBTag2, ...] ) b/c that will make these columns non-indexable and/or hard to query. You may have optimization with XML and JSON columns but those are should not be considered unless the columns are too many and sparse.